# Using RxWorker for api calls in WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-livedata

I am trying to access the work info of a worker class while using RxWorker. Below is the worker class

```
public class OrderSyncWorker extends RxWorker {

@NonNull
@Override
public Single<Result> createWork() {

    List<Order> ordersToBeSynced = databaseRepository.getNonSyncedOrders();
    JSONArray orders = new JSONArray();
    try {
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject(); mApiManager.syncOrders(request).flatMap((Function<ApiResponse, Single<Result>>) apiResponse -> {
            if (apiResponse.getSuccess() == 1) {
                databaseRepository.syncAllOrders();
                mNotificationUtils.showNotification("Orders synced", "", true);
                return Single.just(Result.success());
            } else {
                mNotificationUtils.showNotification("Orders not synced", "Unknown error", true);
                return Single.just(Result.failure());
            }
        }).onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
            mNotificationUtils.showNotification("Orders not synced", Utils.parseError(throwable), true);
            return Result.failure();
        });
        subscription.subscribe();
        return subscription;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return Single.just(Result.failure());
    }
}
```

}

This is how i initialize work request.

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();
    OneTimeWorkRequest orderSyncRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(OrderSyncWorker.class)
            .setInputData(new Data.Builder().putString("macId", macId).build())
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .addTag("sync_orders")
            .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(orderSyncRequest);
```

Tried getting the workinfo livedata like this

```
  workInfos = WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfosByTagLiveData("sync_orders");


viewModel.observeonWorkStatus().observe(this, new Observer<List<WorkInfo>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<WorkInfo> workInfos) {
            if (workInfos == null || workInfos.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            WorkInfo workInfo = workInfos.get(0);

            boolean finished = workInfo.getState().isFinished();
            if (!finished) {
                syncButton.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                syncButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

But the observer is not getting hit. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the code where you enqueue the Worker?

Comment: WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(orderSyncRequest);

Comment: Can you add to the question how you build the WorkRequest also?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

First, a personal note about not using a string literal for your tag, please consider defining a constant for it:

```
static final String TAG_SYNC_ORDERS = "SYNC_ORDERS";
```

Looking at your code it seems that you get a LiveData from your WorkRequest as:

```
LiveData<List<WorkInfo>> workInfos = WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfosByTagLiveData("sync_orders");
```

but then you use another LiveData(?) from the ViewModel:

```
viewModel.observeonWorkStatus()
```

I assume that these are the same. If not, well that's a problem.

Rewriting now your LiveData observer:

```
static final String TAG_SYNC_ORDERS = "SYNC_ORDERS";

LiveData<List<WorkInfo>> workInfos = WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfosByTagLiveData(TAG_SYNC_ORDERS);
workInfos.observe(this, listOfWorkInfo -> {

    // If there are no matching work info, do nothing
    if (listOfWorkInfo == null || listOfWorkInfo.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    // We only care about the one output status.
    WorkInfo workInfo = listOfWorkInfo.get(0);
    boolean finished = workInfo.getState().isFinished();

    if (!finished) {
        syncButton.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        syncButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

You can refer to the [WorkManager codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#7) for more a similar sample.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. But there is a confusion. viewmodel is observing the livedata emitted by workmanager from the activity.I forgot to write it there. There is a method called 
    public LiveData<List<WorkInfo>> observeonWorkStatus() {
        return workInfos;
    }
And view is observing on this workInfos live data. But my problem is this observer is not getting hit